# Price Rule based on percentage in attribute in M 2.4x

Tags: magento2.4, special-price, price-rules

Is there a way (without coding) or  a plug-in with which I can define a attribute that holds a percentage per SKU which is then set to a price rule?

```
SKU   %   Price   Special Price
1     5   100€    95€
2     10  120€    108€
3     20  120€    96€
```

So if a user types in "BlackFriday" in the Checkout field for rabtes the user gehts the special prices like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Cart Price Rules to achieve that.
From the Admin sidebar, navigate to Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rules > Create a new rule:

1. Filled all required fields.
2. In the **Coupon** field, select **Specific Coupon**. Set **Coupon Code** is BlackFriday
3. In the **Conditions** section:
   3.1. Add a new condition, select **Product attribute combination**
   3.2. Add a new sub-condition, select SKU as the condition. After that, filled in your SKU.
4. In the **Actions** section:
   4.1. In the **Apply** field, select **Percent of product price discount**.
   4.2. In the **Discount** field, set the discount amount.
5. Save the rule, you're done.

[image]

You need to repeat these steps to create other rules for other SKUs which has different discount.

Comment: If this answer helps you resolve your issue, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: Yes in general that would work, but its not realy dynamic, we need magento to choose the percentage from a attribute field of the SKU itself.

Comment: As far as I know, Magento default does not support that feature without any customizing code.

Answer (score 0):

The default way is to create specific coupons and those can be set to be applicable by default or when a customer enters a coupon.

If you can further elaborate on your objective as to why you want a different approach rather then the given Magento coupon approach.

On times a proper approach and configuration can save your coding efforts and objective can be achieved